# Query keeps giving me duplicate records. How can I fix this?

Tags: sql, duplicates, amazon-athena

I wrote a query which uses 2 temp tables. And then joins them into 1. However, I am seeing duplicate records in the student visit temp table. (Query is below). How could this be modified to remove the duplicate records of the visit temp table?

```
with clientbridge as (Select *
                     from (Select visitorid, --Visid
                                  roomnumber,
                                  room_id,
                                  profid,
                                  student_id,
                                  ambc.datekey,
                                  RANK() over(PARTITION BY visitorid,student_id,profid ORDER BY ambc.datekey desc) as rn
                          from university.course_office_hour_bridge cohd
                           --where student_id = '9999999-aaaa-6634-bbbb-96fa18a9046e'
                           )
                    where rn = 1 --visitorid = '999999999999999999999999999999'---'1111111111111111111111111111111' --and pai.datekey is not null --- 00000000000000000000000000
),

-----------------Data Header Table
studentvisit as
(SELECT
                   --Visit key will allow us to track everything they did within that visit.
          distinct visid_visitorid,
                   --calcualted_visitorid,
                   uniquevisitkey,
                   --channel, -- says the room they're in. Channel might not be reliable would need to see how that operates
                   --office_list, -- add 7 to exact
                   --user_college,
                   --first_office_hour_name,
                   --first_question_time_attended,
                   studentaccountid_5,
                   profid_officenumber_8,
                   studentvisitstarttime,
                   room_id_115,
                   --date_time,
                   qqq144, --Course Name
                   qqq145, -- Course Office Hour Benefit
                   qqq146, --Course Office Hour ID
                   datekey
      FROM university.office_hour_details ohd
           --left_join niversity.course_office_hour_bridge cohd on ohd.visid_visitorid
      where DateKey >='2022-10-01' --between '2022-10-01' and '2022-10-27'
        and (qqq146 <> '')
    )
select
    *
   from clientbridge ab inner join studentvisit sv on sv.visid_visitorid = cb.visitorid
```

I wrote a query which uses 2 temp tables. And then joins them into 1. However, I am seeing duplicate records in the student visit temp table. (Query is below). How could this be modified to remove the duplicate records of the visit temp table?

Comment: The visitorid is correctly being limited in the first query, however, the inner join against the second query in the final result is more than likely bringing in dups from studentvisit, which is not reducing to visitorid ranked by 1.

Comment: I guess that makes sense. Would a different join help resolve the duplicates?

Comment: What duplicates? Both `clientbridge` and `studentvisit` can have multiple entries per `visitorid` (`select distinct` uses all columns in the select for uniqueness check)

Answer (score 0):

I think you may get have a better shot by joining the two datasets in the same query where you want the data ranked, otherwise your rank from query will be ignored within the results from the second query. Perhaps, something like ->

```
;with studentvisit as
(SELECT
                   --Visit key will allow us to track everything they did within that visit.
          distinct visid_visitorid,
                   --calcualted_visitorid,
                   uniquevisitkey,
                   --channel, -- says the room they're in. Channel might not be reliable would need to see how that operates
                   --office_list, -- add 7 to exact
                   --user_college,
                   --first_office_hour_name,
                   --first_question_time_attended,
                   studentaccountid_5,
                   profid_officenumber_8,
                   studentvisitstarttime,
                   room_id_115,
                   --date_time,
                   qqq144, --Course Name
                   qqq145, -- Course Office Hour Benefit
                   qqq146, --Course Office Hour ID
                   datekey
      FROM university.office_hour_details ohd
      
           --left_join niversity.course_office_hour_bridge cohd on ohd.visid_visitorid
      where DateKey >='2022-10-01' --between '2022-10-01' and '2022-10-27'
        and (qqq146 <> '')
)
,clientbridge as (

Select 
    sv.*,
    university.course_office_hour_bridge cohd, --Visid
                                  roomnumber,
                                  room_id,
                                  profid,
                                  student_id,
                                  ambc.datekey,
                                  RANK() over(PARTITION BY sv.visitorid,sv.student_id,sv,profid ORDER BY ambc.datekey desc) as rn
                          from university.course_office_hour_bridge cohd
                          inner join studentvisit sv on sv.visid_visitorid = cohd.visitorid
)

select
    *
   from clientbridge  WHERE rn=1
```

Comment: so for some reason i am getting an error saying that the studentvisit table is not found

Comment: I made a shortened alias and messed up the select -> studentvisit.* should be sv.*. I fixed it above.

Comment: Also, I am not sure what ambc.datekey is referencing but it does not appear to be in scope for your example.

Comment: after the sv.* i removed the DB since it errored out for me. when I ran the query it came back with the same results as the original one. i did remove the ambc.datekey and switched the ORDER by in to av.datekey to see if this could resolve anything, which i do not believe is

Comment: If you want only data relating to each visitor's first appearance then perhaps the RANK function should be more strict -> (PARTITION BY sv.visitorid  ORDER BY datekey desc)